# How does the recursive rule work in gitignore

Tags: git, github, glob, gitignore

In linux, *.c will only match the .c file in the current directory. If you want to match those in subdirectories as well, you need **/*.c. But in gitignore, *.c will ignore all c file in any level of directory.

However,in gitignore, d/*.c only works for ./d/*.c. It doesn't work for deeper level directories,like a/b/d/*.c

So what's the actual rule here? Why d/*.c doesn't recursively apply to all subdirectory while *.c does?

There's an example in the official document that I attach below, but I don't even understand the example:

"For example, a pattern doc/frotz/ matches doc/frotz directory, but not a/doc/frotz directory; however frotz/ matches frotz and a/frotz that is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), you can see the following:

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.

as well as your example

> For example, a pattern `doc/frotz/` matches `doc/frotz` directory, but not `a/doc/frotz` directory; however `frotz/` matches frotz and `a/frotz` that is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file).

So, it will match recursively as long as there is no `/` at the beginning or within the pattern. However, slashes at the end do not matter for whether it is recursive or not.

If you want to match all `*.c` files in a directory called `b` no matter whether that directory is the root or some subdirectory, you can use `**/b/*.c`:

> A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "`foo`" anywhere, the same as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`" anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo`".